# Concatenating strings inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I have a list of string values that can contain numbers or just words and I want to join together all strings that can't be converted to a number format *(int or float)* with a separator character such as `-`. So the output would be:

```
['string1', '862.4', 'string2', '755.84', 'string3-string4', '56.8']
```

I have come up with the following solution that returns an empty list `[]`. I tried to review indexes and edge cases but I can't find a way of fixing it. At first I thought that it was going to throw an `IndexError` exception, but the code just runs fine, except for the wrong output it gives:

```
s = "string1 862.4 string2 755.84 string3 string4 56.8"
l = s.split(" ")

out = []
for i in range(len(l)):
  if l[i-1].isalpha() and l[i].isalpha():
    out[i-1] = f"{out[i-1]}-{out[i]}"

print(out)
```

**Actual output:**

```
[]
```

Comment: The docs say about `isalpha`: *"Return True if all characters in the string are alphabetic"*. This is not true for any of the words in your input. If it were, your code would give a runtime error on `out[i-1]`.

Comment: @trincot I was expecting an Index error but, it seems the code runs fine. It might be this function `isalpha()`. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You don't get a Index error since when `i == 0`, l[i-1] equals l[-1] which references the last word in l. (which is not what you want).

Answer (score 3):

This is something you could potentially use regex to solve. Here's a solution I came up with which is quite concise and I think can account for edge cases that might arise in your use-case:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile('(?: |^)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?: |$)')
final_array = [x.replace(' ', '-') for x in re.split(regex, s) if x != '']

# >>> final_array
# ['string1', '862.4', 'string2', '755.84', 'string3-string4', '56.8']
```

The central part of that regex `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` is just a check for numbers which can include a floating point and sign, ie. anything of the following examples: `'0', '-2', '1.50', '-3.1415'`

The reason we want to check `if x != ''` is because if the decimal numbers happen to fall at the end or start of the string, then `re.split` will put an empty string on the outer end of the split

Answer (score 2):

The docs say about [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are alphabetic

This is not true for any of the words in your input. If it were, your code would give a runtime error on `out[i-1]` as that is a reference to an index that does not exist in `out` -- `out` is empty.

The `if` block never enters. So the error inside that block is hidden. But the right hand side of the assignment should reference `l[i]`, not `out[i]`, and you should use `out.append`, not `out[i-1]=`

Here is a correction:

```
s = "string1 862.4 string2 755.84 string3 string4 56.8"
l = s.split(" ")

out = []
addnew = True
for word in l:
    try:
        float(word)
    except:  # It's not a number
        if addnew:  # First time in series?
            out.append(word)
            addnew = False
        else:  # Extend the non-number string series
            out[-1] += f"-{word}"
    else:  # It's a number
        out.append(word)
        addnew = True

print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

using itertools and re modules:

```
from re import fullmatch
from itertools import groupby

s = "string1 string0 862.4 111 555 string2 755.84 string3 string4 string5 56.8"
out = ['-'.join(g) for _,g in groupby(s.split(), lambda x: fullmatch(r'[\d\.]+',x))]

>>> out

['string1-string0',
 '862.4',
 '111',
 '555',
 'string2',
 '755.84',
 'string3-string4-string5',
 '56.8']
```

Comment: Very nice use of `groupby` + `regex` here.  Upvote.